# Apache to HttpUrlConnection conversion

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

I have the following code with is an api for a store product. The problem is that the apache library has depreciated so I cannot implement it in android studio. I have tried to convert it to HttpUrlConnection, But I am not getting any output, for now I just want to return it to textview. Any suggestions?

Old library:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    try
    {
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://dev.tescolabs.com/product/");

        builder.setParameter("gtin", "{string}");
        builder.setParameter("tpnb", "{string}");
        builder.setParameter("tpnc", "{string}");
        builder.setParameter("catid", "{string}");

        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");


        // Request body
        StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{body}");
        request.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank but I have already started the work on that one so want to finish with it

Comment: You are first of all appending the same string in `HttpUtlConnection` and secondly not using the `StringBuilder` you are appending to in your `ingredientsView`.

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky What output are you getting now? Because from your code it seems you are appending `results` again and again to your `stringBuilder`.

Comment: I updated the code there. I am not getting any output at all. @SandeepRandhawa

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky `TextView ingredientsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIngredients);
        ingredientsView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());`. Try this.

Comment: thanks, but I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` now....

Comment: Android does not have main methods. How are you running that? You might want to look at Okhttp or Volley instead to avoid an AsyncTask

Comment: Edit your question to include the logcat, if you're getting an error

Comment: The first solution is an example from online which works in linux terminal but not on android studio as it doesnt have the apache library anymore. The second one is what I am running. I am wondering how I would go about to converting the first one to a newer library such as HttpUrlConnection

Comment: For HttpURLConnection, I don't really know why but sometimes my local server doesn't return any response if I don't send any request (which is quite awkward). So i suggest you send a blank request and re-test.